# Stop function so price isnt less than -500 Java

Tags: java, loops, terminate

I've ran into a problem with a method in my program, the task i have been set involves stopping the if statement from running after the balance hits -500, i'v tried if(price < buy && balance > -500) and the current one, while(balance > -500) gives me the result of -594 but the expected result is -495.

although if i take out the {} for the while loop and place a break; right next to the while() it just runs through the junit test which uses a method on the subject class(using observer strategy) to change the price(in this case its setting the price to 0.99 7 times).
 From my testing the current solution gives the closest answer, but the part I'm asking for help with is stopping it so it doesn't go over the -500 mark.
'
Thanks in advance and if you want me to add in any more code to help, let me know

```
     @Override
        public double getBalance() {
           System.out.println("balance  " + price);
           while(balance > -500)break;
                if( price < buy ){
                        outcome = price * increment;
                        System.out.println("OUT   " + outcome + "   ");
                }else if(price > sell  && portfolio >= 100){

                        income = price * increment;
                }

                double total = income - outcome;
                balance = balance + total;

            }
            return balance;
        }
```

edit - ok ive indented it a bit better i hope

Comment: `while(balance > -500)break;` this statement will never do anything.

Comment: yeah, i missed that bit of legacy code when i posted, it should have been a bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that there are no checks if a `balance - total` will go below -500 before the next iteration begins; simplest way to do this with your current code would be:

```
double total = income - outcome;
if(balance + total >= -500) {
    balance = balance + total;
} else {
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now, so everytime i do a while statement similar to what i've just done, i should always have an if statement to check the potential output meets the while statement instead presuming/hoping the while statement will check it correctly?